# Spock Mock internal Date object

Tags: testing, groovy, specifications, spock

I am returning a string from the groovy utility class. The method is
return "${new SimpleDateFormate("dd_MM_yyyy").format(new Date())}"

I want to test this method with my date. Can I mock the new Date() as 2016-01-14.
If it is possible, how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not change the method to take a date as a parameter, then it's easily testable?

Though you appear to be testing that simple date format works. I believe oracle have you covered

Comment: I am trying to find out the way, otherwise this is not simple date format solution.

Comment: You either need a method that returns a date, which you can then mock, or to inject a class with a method that returns a date, and you can mock that. Our just pass the date into the method as I suggest above

Comment: Whichever way you cut it, you need to get the `new Date()` out of that method in the utility class, as it's untestable as it stands